Updating from MySQL 5.7 to 8 resulted in double encoding existing UTF=8 characters
I recently updated MySQL on several servers from 5.7 to 8. The delay was due to a number of other compatibility updates we had to do on websites/apps running on these servers. We were already using UTF-8 for everything and had no issues with foreign characters, etc.
But after the update, we noticed some usernames in some apps were mangled.
For example, a user Zoë was now ZoÃƒÂ«
Looking into this further, I see that MySQL has somehow "double encoded" the previous 2-byte encodings.
In MySQL 5.7, the ë in Zoë was stored as 2 bytes, c3 ab (in ASCII this is Ã«)
But now, MySQL 8 has taken EACH of those bytes and re-encoded it as a separate character!
so, it encoded Ã as c3 83, and it encoded « as c2 ab,
and now I'm left with ÃƒÂ« instead of Ã«
I'm using PHP 8.1.28 and php.ini has default_charset=UTF-8
And for MySQL, here is some output:
> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                            |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8mb4                          |
| character_set_connection | utf8mb4                          |
| character_set_database   | utf8mb4                          |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                           |
| character_set_results    | utf8mb4                          |
| character_set_server     | utf8mb4                          |
| character_set_system     | utf8mb3                          |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/local/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------------+
8 rows in set (0.01 sec)


Does anyone know why this happened or how I can fix it?

Wild guess, but did this upgrade entail dumping the entire DB to a SQL file and then loading it back into the new version of mysql?

@Sammitch yes. Is that the issue?

It's likely that one operation or the other [or both] did not set the charset correctly.

@Sammitch after more searching, I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf-8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored
and it mentions "double encoding" which is what I'm experiencing. I'm going to have to read more about it.

I'm unclear as to why you expect "Ã«" at all. Why should it not be just "ë"?

And we can't really be any more helpful because we don't know how you loaded the data into the DB or how it was actually stored in the DB. We can assume that it was stored as Zoë using utf8mb4 but how does the ASCII encoding come into play here? Did you accidently use the horrible utf8encode() function somewhere in your PHP code? Did you forget to change latin1 charset to utf8mb4 somewhere in your process?

There's also the distinct possibility that the data was never actually stored correctly, and the new version/settings have just exacerbated the existing issue.

@Dharman I appreciate the comments and now I realize that there are MANY possible solutions, depending on how each case has moved their data through various forms and code. I have a LOT of code to check and its possible the utf8encode() function may have been used somewhere, although I don't remember ever using it.

@Sammitch thanks for your comments too. And yes, I have to go through all of the processes a step at a time to see where the data got converted or stored incorrectly.
